# Matlab: Función con For Loop y Plot no grafica

Tags: bucle-for, matlab, plot

Buen día. Creé una fucnión donde se grafica pero no se arroja la gráfica. El código a continuación es de un vector `K` 1X1.

```
C=240e-6;
L=50e-6;
d=13e-3;
l=30.5e-2;
Vc=10;
Ic(d,l,C,L,Vc)

function ic = Ic(d,l,C,L,Vc)
    K=0.27*(d/l)^(2/3)*(C/L)^(1/3);
    V=0:0.1:Vc;
    ic=0.27*K(i)*V.^(4/3);
    plot(V,ic)
end
```

Salida:

```
ans = 1×101    
         0    0.0007    0.0018    0.0030    0.0044    0.0060    0.0076    0.0093    0.0111    0.0130    0.0150    0.0170    0.0191    0.0213    0.0235    0.0258    0.0281    0.0304    0.0329    0.0353    0.0378    0.0404    0.0429    0.0456    0.0482    0.0509    0.0536    0.0564    0.0592    0.0621    0.0649    0.0678    0.0708    0.0737    0.0767    0.0797    0.0828    0.0859    0.0890    0.0921    0.0953    0.0985    0.1017    0.1049    0.1082    0.1115    0.1148    0.1181    0.1215    0.1249
```